# Tricky algorithm for finding alternative route in graph with few added edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, tree, edges

Okay, so I found this a bit tricky.

Basically, you have a directed graph (let's call it the base graph), that has some leaves and a node with 0 indegree that is called root. It may contain cycles.

From that base graph, a tree has been made, that contains the root and all leaves, and some connection between them. The nodes and edges that are not needed to connect the root to the leaves are left out.

Now imagine one or more edges in the tree "break", and can no longer be used. The problem now is to

a) If possible, find an alternative route(s) to the disconnected node(s), introducing as few previously unused edges from the base graph as possible.

b) If not possible, select which edges to "repair", repairing as few edges as possible to get all leaves connected again.

This is supposed to represent an electrical grid, and the breaks are power outages.

If just one edge is broken, it is easy enough. But say you have a graph with 100 leaves, 500 edges, and 50 edges break. Now to find which combination of adding previously unused edges from the base graph, and if necessary repairing some edges, to connect all leaves, seems like a very hard problem.

I imagined one could do some sort of brute force, where ALL combinations of unused edges, from using 1 to all of them, are tested. Or if repairs are needed, testing ALL combinations of repairs with all combinations of new edges. When the amount of edges get high, this seems to me very very inefficient.

My question is, does anyone have any smart ideas to how this could be done in a more efficient way? I hope I explained it well enough.

Comment: Do you just need the *leaves* connected, or every node in the tree?

Comment: Just the leaves, but only using nodes and edges that already exist in the base graph.

Comment: Is it required that the edges you add (or repair) cause the resulting graph to be a tree again?  Or is it OK if some leaf is connected to the root via two or more different paths?

Comment: @j_random_hacker It is required that it is a tree, i.e. one and only one path from the root to each leaf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an NP-hard problem, and I'll explain why. Imagine that you have three layers of nodes: the root node, a layer of intermediate connecting nodes, and then a layer of leaf nodes. Edges go from root to intermediate nodes, and from an intermediate node to some subset of leaf nodes. Suppose you have some choice of intermediate nodes and edges to leaf nodes that gives you a connected tree graph, where each intermediate node has an edge to only one leaf node. Now imagine all edges in the reduced graph are removed. Then to find the minimum number of edges needed to add to repair the graph, this is equivalent to finding the minimum number of remaining intermediate nodes whose edges cover all of the leaf nodes. This is equivalent to the set cover problem for the leaf nodes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem and is NP-hard. Thus there is almost certainly no fast algorithm for your problem in the worst case (unless P = NP). Maybe if you bound the number of edges that are removed, you can come up with a polynomial time algorithm where the exponent in the polynomial depends (hopefully weakly) on how many edges were removed.

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully whatever I come up with is reasonably fast for the number of edges that will be removed.

Comment: Excellent observation. It's interesting - this only works because you have to connect all the leaves but nothing else. I wonder if there's some analogous difficulty result if you also have to get the internal nodes connected to the root?

Comment: @templatetypedef: Seems like connecting the root to all nodes is easier as per my answer.

Comment: +1.  I'm wondering whether the OP forgot to mention a constraint, though -- it might be that the new graph that connects all the leaves to the root is also required to be a (directed) tree.  But then the problem becomes equivalent to Exact Cover, which is still NP-Hard. :(

Comment: @j_random_hacker I did assume the new graph has to be a directed tree, which is why I said that the old internal nodes only had one edge to a leaf, and (implicitly) that in the new graph, each leaf would only have one edge from one of the previously unused internal node. Thus the number of edges to leaves is equal to the number of leaves in the new graph, and the only question is how to minimize the number of new internal nodes used which is equivalent to traditional Set Cover.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the start to a good efficient heuristic/solution would be to weight the edges. A couple simple approaches (not the most space efficient) as to how you could weight the edges based on the total number of edges are listed below.

1. If using any number of undamaged edges is better than using a single alternative edge and using any number of alternative edges is better than a single damaged edge.

   ```
   Undamaged edge: 1
   Alternative edge: E
   Damaged edge: E^2
   ```

   In the case of `100` vertices and `500` edges, alternative edges would be weighted as `500`, while damaged edges would be weighted as `250000`.
2. If using any number of undamaged edges is better than using a single alternative edge *or* a single damaged edge.

   ```
   Undamaged edge: 1
   Alternative/damaged edge: E
   ```

   In the case of `100` vertices and `500` edges, alternative/damaged edges would be weighted as `500`.

It seems like you then try a number of approaches to find either the exact solution or a heuristic result. The main suggestion I have for an algorithm is below.

- Find the [directed minimium spanning tree](http://www.ce.rit.edu/~sjyeec/dmst.html). If you use the weighting listed above, then I believe the result is optimum if I'm understanding things correctly.

  - Although, if you have intermediate nodes (nodes that are neither the root or a leaf), then this is likely to result in an overestimating heuristic. In which case, you might be able to get around it by running all pairs all shortest paths first and use the path costs for that as input for the directed minimium spanning tree algorithm, but that's probably a heuristic as well.

Comment: Seems like a decent heuristic to me, although as you say, it unnecessarily forces in all internal vertices.  I would suggest a greedy postprocessing step in which every alternative/damaged edge ending at an internal vertex is examined to see whether it can be safely deleted (that is, whether all the leaves that are descendants of this internal vertex can be covered by adding other undamaged edges).  Repeat until no more edges to internal vertices can be deleted.

Comment: Great answer and comment, I thought of both of these things and I think this is the approach I will go by. Thanks for putting exact numbers on it.